Weird shading on meshes when adding NormalMap to material
I am trying to make a render of the interior of a race car I made but as soon as I add the NormalMap textures of the carbon the objects have weird shading all over the place:

Without NormalMap there is no problem:

And it looks perfect in-game:

Do you have any idea how to solve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!
